# How to resolved Multiple Address in Bonjour based ios application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bonjour, cfsocket

I am trying to Implement Banjour based application in ios. I implement success fully also sending and receiving data to one iphone to another iphone.
After browsing the services all other device in the work. and display in to the  Table.

[image]

Now i want to select some devices in the table view, and send data to the selected devices

[image]

For that i created only one socket in each device.

```
CFSocketContext socketCtxt = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};   
    witap_socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, (CFSocketCallBack)&TCPServerAcceptCallBack, &socketCtxt);

    if (witap_socket != NULL)        
    {
        protocolFamily = PF_INET6;
    }
    else 
    {
        witap_socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, kCFSocketAcceptCallBack, (CFSocketCallBack)&TCPServerAcceptCallBack, &socketCtxt);        
        if (witap_socket != NULL)
        {
            protocolFamily = PF_INET;
        }
    }
```

now i want to send data to the selected devices. for that I stored selected NSNetService(ie devices) another NSMutableArray. When used Click the send button particular Action will invoked.

```
-(void)SendActionFunction
{   
       for(int idx=0;idx<[selectedSer count];idx++)
    {
        NSNetService *service = [self.selectedSer objectAtIndex:idx];  
        NSLog(@"service......%@",[service name]);
        self.currentResolve = [self.selectedSer objectAtIndex:idx]; 
        [self.currentResolve setDelegate:self];     
        [self.currentResolve resolveWithTimeout:0.0];
    }
}
```

if i am trying to Resolve address for each device(above code). It will resolve only for first device. and getting error

- **(Error code=-72003]**

one more problem if i resolved   address for a device it automatically  remove  from Tableview.

So my doubts are:

1. Why the selected device revoved?
2. Now i create TCP based socket, How to add destination address  to send data?
3. Is it possible  to send data from single socket to multiple destination?

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple's definition, A CFSocket is a communications channel implemented with a BSD socket.

You have established a socket connection between the devices. But for sending and receiving data, you must make use of NSStreams. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I see you are using Apple's sample code Witap as the reference.

For sending and receiving the data, use [NSStreamDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSStreamDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

What about resolve and send datas 1 device per 1 device ? Sounds easier :D

BTW, there is a really nice socket library I used for a project :

https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket